# Issue getting my web server to work from external devices

Tags: raspberry-pi, webserver, apache2, portforwarding

I am attempting to set up an apache2 web server on my raspberry pi. I am able to connect to it by doing http://localhost:8080 (8080 because my router blocks port 80). Although when I do http://my.pub.lic.ip:8080 the connection times out. I set up port forwarding so that requests going to my router on port 8080 go to my raspberry pi on port 8080. This does not seem to work but I'm also not sure if the port forwarding is the cause or if it is something else. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the web server up and running although for some reason it appears that my isp would only allow it to be hosted securely (as an https page)(I'm not sure if that's the right way to phrase it). To achieve this for free, I used cloudflare's ssl service. A tutorial to set it up for apache2 can be found [here](https://devanswers.co/configure-cloudflare-origin-ca-apache/)

Answer (score 1):

Is your web server configured to listen on the network interface besides localhost?

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html

*For example, to make the server accept connections on both port 80 and port 8000, on all interfaces, use:*

```
    Listen 80
    Listen 8000
```

*To make the server accept connections on port 80 for one interface, and port 8000 on another, use*

```
    Listen 192.0.2.1:80
    Listen 192.0.2.5:8000
```

Comment: I have it configured as Listen 8080

Answer (score 0):

You can try using nmap by finding your router's public IP and on the raspberry pi type `nmap my.pub.lic.ip` This will show you what services are actually being published to the world. This gives more insight to the problem.

Comment: It says that port 8080 is in a filtered state and is an http-proxy service. What does that tell me?

Comment: 8080 should be open. If it is filtered that means your router may be doing something to the packets. Check your firewall and ICMP settings. Setting a router to not respond to ICMP requests can also be a cause of filtered ports.

Comment: I could not find anything about ICMP in my router settings

Comment: Can you access your webserver on a device on the same network?